# Want to stop a function when a button is clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I have written some code for my Shopify store with jQuery. The work is that when a customer will come to my shop he will see a product added to the cart already.

The code works perfectly but the problem is when he clicks the remove button to remove that product the product is not being removed. It's actually removing but it's added again to the cart.

Is there any solution for this? I have an idea that if someone clicks the remove button then the function will not run again. Please tell me what the code should be?

```js
Shopify = Shopify || {};
Shopify.cart = {{ cart | json }};

if (Shopify.cart !=='undefined' && Shopify.cart.items.length === 0) {
  jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
    quantity: 1,
    id: 36507787624610,
  }).always(function(data){
    window.location.reload();
  })
}
```

Comment: The question is, why are you automatically adding anything to the basket at all?

Comment: You could use session or local storage to save some flag when user clicked remove button and avoid adding item in case the flag presents. Or a better yet rethink your idea because it sounds like a bad UX ;)

Comment: Echoing the above comments: I trust that whatever page the user was on that took them to your site has properly prepared user expectations for an item being added to their cart. You need look at how to use cookies. Let's say you use an "ItemAdded" variable which you save as 'TRUE' to a cookie. Check for the "ItemAdded" cookie pre-existence and if not found add the item to cart, then set the cookie.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or a demo link of your functionality?
why is the function is always recurring. you are talking about a Stop button but where is the Add button or Remove button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what theme you are using but this what you can do with your theme. I used debut theme.

Add following data attribute in your remove button html

`item-id="{{ item.id }}"`

After adding the above line, in debut theme it will look like this.

```
<a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" item-id="{{ item.id }}" class="text-link text-link--accent" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.remove' | t: product: item.title }}" data-cart-remove>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</a>
```

Add the JS code in your theme.jS file. (Change the Variant ID according to your product)

```
//Adding product in cart
  $.getJSON('/cart.js',function( data ) {
    
    $( data.items ).each(function( index, item ) {
      
      //Replace the ID with your variantID
      if(item.id == 30329455837287) {
        localStorage.setItem("item_removed", "1");
      }
    });

  });
  
  
  $('a.text-link.text-link--accent').click(function(){
    var variant_id = $(this).attr('item-id');
    
    console.log(variant_id);
    
    if(variant_id == 30329455837287){
      localStorage.setItem("item_removed", "1");
    }
    
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    if( localStorage.getItem("item_removed") == "0" || localStorage.getItem("item_removed") == null ) {
      $.post('/cart/add.js', {
        quantity: 1,
        //Replace the ID with your variantID
        id: 30329455837287
      });
    }
  }, 500);

});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what theme you are using @mh_Pavel?